# PHP uploads non-readable images

Tags: php, image, upload

I really need another brain here. I have a script that makes three different versions of an image, and saves them in different folders (large, medium, thumbnail).  It resizes them and puts them in their folders, but the large one is not readable (the other two are).  It has nothing to do with the folder, so I'm stuck...

Here's my (simplified) code:

```
<?php

    $target_folder = "images/";
    $uploads_dir = $target_folder;

    $upload_image = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];

    $id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $image_name = $id . "." . time();  //this just generates the image name

    $large_name = $target_folder . "large/" . $image_name . ".jpg";
    $medium_name = $target_folder . "medium/" . $image_name . ".jpg";
    $small_name = $target_folder . "small/" . $image_name . ".jpg";

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($upload_image);  //width/height of original image

    $medium_newwidth = $width * 0.60;  //scales image down to 60%
    $medium_newheight = $height * 0.60;

    $small_newwidth = $width * 0.20;  //scales image down to 20%
    $small_newheight = $height * 0.20;

    $large = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);  //here's where I think the problem might be
    $medium = imagecreatetruecolor($medium_newwidth, $medium_newheight);
    $small = imagecreatetruecolor($small_newwidth, $small_newheight);

    imagecopyresized($medium, $large, 0, 0, 0, 0, $medium_newwidth, $medium_newheight, $width, $height);
    imagecopyresized($small, $large, 0, 0, 0, 0, $small_newwidth, $small_newheight, $width, $height);

    imagejpeg($medium, $medium_name, 100);
    imagejpeg($small, $small_name, 100);

    rename($upload_image, $large_name);

?>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like permissions then. What OS are you using? What user:group do you have PHP running as? What user:group is your webserver running as? What user:group do the folders belong too? Is this just a certain image or did you try with others? Also, I would add `__DIR__` to $target_folder so it isn't relative.

Comment: I'm using Mac OsX Mountain Lion.  I'm running as an administrator.

Comment: I didn't ask what *you* were running as - what is PHP/Apache/Nginx running as?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) instead of `rename` if you want to use the original upload. Alternatively you could save the large image like you are doing with the other ones:

```
imagejpeg($large, $large_name, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!!  (I have to wait for 10 minutes until I can mark it as answered)

Comment: +1 Attack data can be saved inside images, I would use `imagejpeg` on the file forcing a GD stream save rather than just moving it to the folder.

Comment: @Xeoncross Agreed, although I would probably add some error handling so that nothing gets saved if I can't create the image to start with.

Comment: @xeoncross: that'll kill image quality by doing a recompress. not a bad thing for preventing an attack , but should be noted in any case.

Comment: @MarcB, it only kills image quality if you save with bad compression or in the wrong format. There is nothing inherit about GD/ImageMagick that kills the image quality. They take time to learn.